# Is it wrong to pass EJBs as parameters to helper classes?

Tags: java, ejb-3.0, ejb

I'm in the situation where I need to create a cache to store certains values which need to be updated from the database. Since this cache needs to be singular, some sort of singleton implementation seems appropriate.

The problem is that this cache also needs access to the database via an EJB, which can't be injected since the cache exists outside of context (and yes, I'm looking forward to the @singleton annotation in EJB3.1).

The obvious solution is to pass the EJB into the cache as a parameter, but passing EJBs outside of context feels wrong, though I can't say why. Is it accepted practice?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do note that you are normally not passing the EJB itself "outside of context". What you are typically passing around is a 'stub'. This stub can be passed around as any other normal object reference. Any calls on it will redirect back to an actual bean instance in the EJB container.

So if you have a cache in say the web module, have a backing bean injected with an EJB (or do a JNDI lookup) and pass that reference to a (static) cache, then I don't see a fundamental problem with that.

For all intends and purposes, the @Singleton annotation was indeed made for something like this. Hope you'll able to use it soon ;)

Answer (score 0):

The main advantage of EJB is inside container. If you pass it outside you loose all the advantages which a container provide. Why don't you create a method in EJB that return the data you need. And the you can do, for example, JNDI lookup and call that method. In this way EJB will stay in the container and you will get your data.

Comment: Because the cache needs to be common for all instances of that stateless session bean.

Comment: May be then you try to do what you expect from @Singleton. Make it a singleton bean yourself.